# Почему {} > {} == true?

Tags: javascript

Почему следующий код работает именно так? Как он преобразовывает объекты и к какому типу приводит при сравнении?

```
let obj  = {};
let obj2 = {};
obj > obj2 // true
```

Comment: Вы, наверное, имели в виду `>=`?

Comment: @Александр, а какая разница? :)

Comment: @Grundy , ну так у меня, например, `{}>{}` не дают true, в отличие от `{}>={}`. Вот я и предположил, что автор имел в виду второе

Comment: @Александр, да :-D забавно, `>=` это `не меньше`, а так как меньше возвращает false - `>=` возвращает `true`, это и с `<=` сработает :-D парадокс: `a >= b` и `a<=b` но `a != b` :-D

Comment: Оба операнда приводятся к строке `[object Object]` и сравниваются как строки. Так что у вас ошибка сравнение `>` даст false

Comment: @Grundy из разряда `console.log(0 == '0', 0 == [], '0' == []);`.

Comment: не вижу там true, попробуйте в консоли: `({} > {}) == true // false`

Answer (score 3):

Что-то я не вижу никакого `true`.

```js
let obj = {};
let obj2 = {};
console.log(obj > obj2, obj2 > obj, obj == obj2);
```